# XDMoD : error "no aggregate table. have you ingested your data"

Tags: metrics, job-scheduling, hpc, pbs, torque

For running the XDMoD from http://open.xdmod.org/
on CentOS virtual machine. The command

```
xdmod-shredder -v -r resource -f pbs -d /var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting
```

runs correctly and the ingester command

```
xdmod-ingestor -v
```

also. But still error msg shows up when I open up web browser saying " have you ingested your data". the problem is still unknown. kindly help.

Comment: Could you please confirm that the filenames in `/var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting` are formatted as `YYYYMMDD`? Please add the output from `ls /var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting | tail` to your post

Comment: `accounting]# ls -l | tail`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10387 Jun  2 15:04 20170329`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    31354 Jun  2 15:04 20170330`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13808847 Jun  2 15:04 20170331`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8819785 Jun  2 15:04 20170401`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     4048 Jun  2 15:04 20170402`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   110812 Jun  2 15:04 20170403`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     6854 Jun  2 15:04 20170404`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    20544 Jun  2 15:04 20170405`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2833 Jun  2 15:04 20170406`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    76283 Jun  2 15:04 20170407`

Comment: please let me know the solution. ` Error :Aggregate table not found, have you ingested your data? #0 {main}' .    it still shows up.